# Using Ajax and jQuery autocomplete to build table rows from Ajax response(Json)

Tags: jquery, ajax, netbeans

How can I use the Ajax autocomplete to build a table row. The autocomplete code is working. If the user search for value and click on which one they want, I want to add that value to my table right there. If they search again, I want to append that result under the first result. but I can't find a way to build a table row from the respond. Here is the code.

> **One more thing, I am reading a son file:**

This is my Ajax, jQuery code

```js
$.support.cors = true;
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var items = [];
    $("#addclass").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            $.ajax({
                url: "php/Classes.php",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#search-box").css("background","#C0C0C0");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (value, i) {
                        var text = value.value;
                        if (text && (!request.term || matcher.test(text))) {
                            return {
                                ID: value.ID,
                                value: value.value
                            };
                        }
                    }));         
                }
            });
        }
    });

    
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
    margin: 0% 0px 0px 20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 15px 0px;
}

th, td {
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;;
    text-align: center;
}

This is my HTML code
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/profile.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a8b13015aa.js"></script>
        
        <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script>tinymce.init({selector: '#tinymce'});</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/profile.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/tinymce/init-tinymce.js"></script>
        <script src="script/profile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
                    <div class="info">
                        <label id ="classes">My Classes</label>
                        <table class = "table">
                            <p></p>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Course ID</th>
                                <th>Course Name</th>
                                <th>Start Date/End Date</th>
                                <th>Credit Hours</th>
                            </tr>   
                        </table>
                        <br>
                        <label id ="activity">HIGHT AND ACTIVITY</label>
                        <label id = "search"><input type="text" name="addclass" id="addclass" placeholder="Search for course"/></label>
                        <div id ="suggesstion"></div>
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

I was hoping that some could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiarized with jQuery UI, but I've just read the documentation and found out that you can catch the value of the option selected with this event listener: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select.

By default it just autocompletes the input with the value of the selected item, but you can customize it by taking the value of the object "ui" and appending it to the table row.

Here's a very clear explanation https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_autocomplete at the end of the page. I hope this helps you out